# Dropdown icon not showing for q-select quasar-framework

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, quasar-framework, quasar

I am using quasar-framwork with vue-2. I have a q-select item in my vue file and its not showing dropdown incon instead its showing title 'arrow_drop_down' and 'cancel' texts.

Here is what i am seeing :
[image]

What i was expecting :
[image]

my q-select code :

```html
<q-select v-model="attr.category" :options="categories" label="standard" style="margin-right: 3px" float-label="Category" clearable class="col-md-5 IDcategory" @input="reviewModel"/>
```

Any idea what could be the issue here. Any help/clue will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a [Quasar UMD/standalone installation](https://v1.quasar.dev/start/umd#installation), sounds like you're probably missing this stylesheet in your index.html `<head>`

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: I am using quasar-framework and quasar-extra with webpack. Any idea what could be reason for this issue ? I am pretty much new to this quasar framework.

Comment: How did you install quasar?  The [documentation](https://quasar.dev/start/pick-quasar-flavour) has 4 different installation methods.  Starting from scratch they should each lead to a working app if instructions are accurately followed.  Easiest method is Quasar CLI as it is just two commands then answering some prompts to scaffold an entire project. The CLI works with Vite (recommended) and webpack

Comment: I installed quasar-framework as npm package in my nodejs app. I can that package is outdated and was published 5 years back.